# What is the most important element of a drama, beside its message?

Tags: technique, screenwriting, playwriting, dramatic-writing

I am participating in a skit in school about superstition and science.

How much will the presence of emotion attract the attention of the audience? What are other important things to attract attention of audience or to give them a message?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a homework assignment.

Comment: It's not an homework.

Comment: @iamSiddharthYadav Then maybe you can rephrase your question in the context of your own writing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be more about acting rather than writing.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've been told, there are two important parts to a drama: 1) story (or "message" in your words), and 2) characters.

That's because the characters are the medium by which your message is conveyed, and the interaction of the characters produces the plot, or "storyline."

Comment: I disagree. The core of every tale anyone cares about is a person with a need opposed by an obstacle. In other words: character, goal and antagonist (where antagonist need not be a person). Everything else -- plot, emotions, and so on -- follows from there. Stories for small children, that is stories about the discovery of the world, may differ.